When conditional expectation given $A_0=1$ is multiplied by binary random variable $A_0$.
Let $A$ be a binary variable with support $\{0,1\}$, and $X,Y$ can be any arbitrary random variables.
I have checked that $$E\left\{E(Y\mid A=1, X)\,\frac{A}{P(A=1\mid X)}\right\} = E\left\{E(Y\mid A, X)\,\frac{A}{P(A=1\mid X)}\right\}.$$
From that, I have the observation that when multiply by an "indicator" random variable, such as $A$, the conditional expectation on $A=1$ can be change to conditional on random variable $A$ itself.
Now I have a little bit complicated expression as follows, where $A_0$ is a binary variable with support $\{0,1\}$.
I want to check if the equality in step $(a)$ is valid. In short, I want to ask - if it is correct that, when multiplied by an indicator random variable, for any conditional expectation expressions, we can leave it as either $A_0=1$ or $A_0$, right?
\begin{align*}
&E\left\{ E( E[Y\mid A_0=1, X_0, X_1] \mid A_0=1, X_0) \, \frac{A_0}{P(A_0=1\mid X_0)}\right\}\\
&\stackrel{(a)}{=}E\left\{E( E[Y\mid A_0=1, X_0, X_1] \mid A_0, X_0) \, \frac{A_0}{P(A_0=1\mid X_0)}\right\}
\end{align*}
I use a similarly thought process to argue as the very top one, and I think the step $(a)$ is valid. However, I want to double check and seek for any additional insight/rule related to this.
